# Unable to switch window using WebdriverIO (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Currently unable to switch between different browser tabs.

My code contained within my test class:

```
describe('Validate switching of tabs', () => {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.url("https://duckduckgo.com") 
      });
    it('Switch tab', () => {
        browser.newWindow('https://webdriver.io')
        browser.switchToWindow('DuckDuckGo — Privacy, simplified.');
    })
})
```

Seem to be receiving the following exception:

```
[0-0] 2019-07-24T10:22:26.116Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (C:\Users\Gianni Bruno\Desktop\webdriverio-v5\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:371:10)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Gianni Bruno\Desktop\webdriverio-v5\node_modules\webdriver\build\request.js:120:64)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Gianni Bruno\Desktop\webdriverio-v5\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gianni Bruno\Desktop\webdriverio-v5\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gianni Bruno\Desktop\webdriverio-v5\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
[0-0] Error in "Validate switching of tabs Switch tabs"
no such window
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `switchWindow` method instead of the `switchToWindow` method. Read more [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/switchWindow.html).

```
describe('Validate switching of tabs', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.url("https://duckduckgo.com") 
  });

  it('Switch tab', () => {
    browser.newWindow('https://webdriver.io')
    browser.switchWindow('DuckDuckGo — Privacy, simplified.');
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey @Gbru. Happy to help you!)

Comment: what will be browser.switchWindow method parameters for same wewbsite url?

Answer (score 2):

Try using browser.switchWindow(urlOrTitleToMatch)

```
describe('Validate switching of tabs', () => {
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.url("https://duckduckgo.com") 
  });
it('Switch tab', () => {
    browser.newWindow('https://webdriver.io')
    browser.switchWindow('DuckDuckGo — Privacy, simplified.');
})
```

})

Comment: Please check again browser.switchWindow v/s browser.switchToWindow . These are two different methods.